# MSQL IF statement Error

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to retrieve data of multiple parameters from a table of a MySQL based database.

I want check the count of date and if the count is equal to 24, I need to find max and min of multiple parameter and retrieve the data. I've used the below shown query, but it gives syntax error.

```
"SET @cnt=(select count(DATE) from DATA where ID=1111 and     DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00')    \
       IF (@cnt=24) then \
            select MIN(parameter1),max(parameter2) from STATION_DATA where STATION_ID=6216 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00' \
     END IF
```

But it gives syntax error . 
I'm a MySQL beginner and any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created stored procedure to execute these statements or you are simply executing them as single SQL statement?

Comment: The `IF` clause is only available inside stored procedures. For update statements you need to use the `IF()` function.

Comment: no I'm not using a stored procedure. I'm executing it as query through a python console

Answer (score 0):

Following should work, just use the variable `@cnt` as you want in the where clause rather than use the IF statement that is for stored programs.

`SET @cnt=(select count(DATE) from DATA where ID=1111 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00');
select MIN(parameter1),max(parameter2) from STATION_DATA where @cnt=24 and STATION_ID=6216 and DATA_DATE>='2016-01-24 00:00:00' and DATA_DATE<'2016-01-25 00:00:00';`

Answer (score 0):

IF statements is different in queries. Please use following query:

```
SET @cnt=(SELECT COUNT(DATE) FROM DATA WHERE ID = 1111 
       AND DATA_DATE >= '2016-01-24 00:00:00' 
       AND DATA_DATE < '2016-01-25 00:00:00');

SELECT IF(@cnt = 24, MIN(parameter1), '') AS  parameter1,
       IF(@cnt = 24, MAX(parameter2), '') AS  parameter2 
       FROM STATION_DATA WHERE STATION_ID = 6216 
       AND DATA_DATE >= '2016-01-24 00:00:00' 
       AND DATA_DATE <  '2016-01-25 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks I did it slightly another way